# In Views 2, display only one value and leave blank all other values

Tags: views

I have a view that displays all nodes of a content type but I'm trying to display 1 value of a multi-value field and keep the rest of the values of the same field as blank. For example:

One field has 2 values: Yes and No. I'd like to display both nodes in my block in a table but for the column with the Yes/No field, I'd like to show "Yes" but leave blank if value is "No". Can this be done? Thanks

Comment: I would go for a template if I were you. writing logic "if statements" in views are always a pain for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Views PHP](http://drupal.org/project/views_php) module. This allows you to check any field of the view with an if-statement (or wgatever you like). Not really a very nice solution, but simple.